# Float text right even when text falls below image

Tags: html, css

I have an image with text right next to it floating. It works fine for large desktop. But when I reduce device dimensions then the text does not float nicely vertically anymore. Basically, the text goes below the image and takes the full line. How to get the text always to float right (vertically aligned nicely) regardless device dimensions / image height?? I have Bootstrap template, so responsiveness is key to my site. I know I can make my image bigger, but that doesn´t fit the layout of my site.

My Fiddle... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/ff5bx46f/1/)

HTML:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></div>

        <div class="model">
            Mercedes
        </div>

        <div class="description">
            the best the best the best the best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the best bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestbestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the best
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.img {
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
    padding:0 0 5px 45px;
    position:relative;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block
}

.img img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:17px
}

.model {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#5A5A5A;
    padding:0 0 10px 55px;
    width:100%
}

.description {
    font-size:14px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-weight:400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you used bootstrap. Why not use media object instead of make an extra css ?

Read this for reference : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media

See this snippet.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="media">
      <div class="media-left">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" >
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
        Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
         Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
         Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff5bx46f/2/)

Removed  `display:inline-block` as it does not work with `float`

added bottom `margin` to push your text down

---

```css
.img {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  padding: 0 0 5px 45px;
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 35px 0;
}
.img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 17px
}
.model {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #5A5A5A;
  padding: 0 0 10px 55px;
  width: 100%
}
.description {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 400
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img">
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>

  <div class="model">
    Mercedes
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    the best the best the best the best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the best bestthe best the
    best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestbestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the bestthe best the best the best
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, use a `<table>`. That makes it nice and clean. Stucture:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr align="middle">
            <td colspan="2">Title</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <img src="#">
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                text
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

There are **two columns**, so colspan must be 2 to span the whole width of the table and to center the text `align="middle"`. And **valign** means vertical align, so that the img and text ist always on **top**.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ff5bx46f/4/)